# Как правильно распарсить xml?

Tags: python, xmlparser

Добрый день. Необходимо сделать парсинг xml и записать в csv на python примерно такого вида:

```
<Root>
    <SubRoot>
        <Level1>A</Level1>
        <Level2>B</Level2>
        <Level3>C</Level3>
        <Level4>D</Level4>
   </SubRoot>

   <SubRoot>
       <Level1>1</Level1>
       <Level2>2</Level2>
       <Level3>3</Level3>
       </SubRoot>
</Root>
```

Мой код

```
for subroot in root.findall('SubRoot'):
    level1 = subroot.find('Level1').text
    level2 = subroot.find('Level2').text
    level3 = subroot.find('Level3').text
    level4 = subroot.find('Level4').text
    print level1
    print level2
    print level3
    print level4
```

В первом **SubRoot** содержится 4 уровня, во втором их 3. Строка l`evel4 = subroot.find('Level4').text` вызывает ошибку. 

Как сделать так, чтобы в заголовке столба файла csv попадали 4 уровня, первая строка заполнялась вся, а в последней ячейке второй строки было пусто. 
Пример в изображении ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить пустую строку, если элемента не существует:

```
level4 = subroot.findtext('Level4', default='')
```